# LUIS Download application query logs empty

Tags: azure-language-understanding

In LUIS, when I download application query logs all I receive is 1 line with headers:
Query   UTC DateTime    Response

This is via the web portal (cloud icon) and via the API.  I do not have log=false in the query URL

Anyone know how to fix this or what the issue is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MS fixed this for me, it was an issue their end.